# VBA: for loop for multiple variables

Tags: excel, vba

I really new at VBA, and I'm trying to programme a for loop as part of my code. So what I want to do is that for each row in my selected range (Price in my input), I want to take an average of High, Low and Price (which are inputs in my function, I've tried listing all 3 as ranges but I run into errors)

Will really appreciate any help!

I've attached part of my code as a reference!

```
Function MFI(High, Low, Price As Range, Volume, Price0)

'function takes in 5 inputs over the past 14 days (range that user selects will be 14 rows)
'high price (column C), low price (column D), close price (column E), volume (column G), Price0 (first close price in the entire spreadsheet)

Dim Pos, Neg, MF_ratio, MF_index, Typ_price, Flow, Pre_Typ_Price, Count As Long

Dim day As Range

For Each day In Price
'for loop to loop through the range of close prices selected

Typ_price = (day.Value + High + Low) / 3
'typical price is the average of a day's high price, low price and close price
```

When I run this function, I get #Value!

Comment: Start declaring all variables type _excplicitly_ (otherwise they will ben assumed as of `Variant` type) and with their _proper_ type: if `High` and `Low` are `Range` objects then declare them as such. and so on.

Comment: Which errors in which line? Please be more specific. Also show a `[mcve]` how is the function called which values, which data is used. What do you expect as result? • Note that if you declare `Dim Pos, Neg, … , Count As Long` **only** `Count` is of type `Long` but all the other are of type `Variant` you must declare a type for **every** variable: `Dim Pos As Long, Neg As Long, … , Count As Long`. Also declare a type for every variable in your function `MFI(High, Low, Price As Range, Volume, Price0)`.

Comment: How are you calling your function?

Comment: Sorry with `[mcve]` in the comment above I mean this link [mcve].